# program that provides the Hurricane Category based on the Saffir-Simpson Scale

Tags: c++

Develop a program that provides the Hurricane Category based on the Saffir-Simpson Scale. The program prompts the user for miles per hour vs Kilometers per hour. The user will enter the windspeed (either mph or km/h) and the program will display the category and provide a warning if the hurricane is a Category 4 or above. Password protect the program.  Flowchart the logic of the program.

This is my current code, that i can't get to output the individual hurricane levels

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string pass = "battlebot";
    string input;

    cout << " Enter password : ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input != pass)
    {
        cout << "uh uh uh you did not say the magic word" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        string mile_per_hour = "MPH";
        string mesurment;

        cout << " Please enter MPH for Miles per hour or KMH for Kilometers per hour " << endl;
        cin >> mesurment;
        if (mesurment != mile_per_hour)
        {
            double KMH_catone;
            KMH_catone = 119 >= 153;
            double KMH_cattwo;
            KMH_cattwo = 154 >= 177;
            double KMH_catthree;
            KMH_catthree = 178 >= 208;
            double KMH_catfour;
            KMH_catfour = 209 >= 251;
            double KMH_catfive;
            KMH_catfive = 1000 >= 252;
            double kmh_windspeed;
            
            cout << " Please enter wind speed in KMH ";
            cin >> kmh_windspeed;

            if (kmh_windspeed < 119 )
            {
                cout << " Tis but a windy day " << endl;
            }
            else if (kmh_windspeed == KMH_catone)
            {
                cout << " Grab yer hat and hang on for a Catergory 1 Huricane " << endl;
            }
            else if (kmh_windspeed == KMH_cattwo)
            {
                cout << " Whoo dogies your in for a Catergory 2 Huricane " << endl;
            }
            else if (kmh_windspeed == KMH_catthree)
            {
                cout << " Well you just hunker on down, there partner its a Catergory 3 Huricane " << endl;
            }
            else if (kmh_windspeed == KMH_catfour)
            {
                cout << " Yall best just get on out of there a Catergory 4 Huricane is a coming your way " << endl;

            }
            else if ( kmh_windspeed == KMH_catfive )
            {
                cout << " Dat no good low down dirty Catergory 5 Huricane is a comming and its time to go " << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double MPH_catone;
            MPH_catone = 95 >= 94;
            double MPH_cattwo;
            MPH_cattwo = 110 >= 96;
            double MPH_catthree;
            MPH_catthree = 129 >= 111;
            double MPH_catfour;
            MPH_catfour = 156 >= 130;
            double MPH_catfive;
            MPH_catfive = 1000 >= 157;
            double mph_windspeed;

            cout << " Please enter wind speed in MPH ";
            cin >> mph_windspeed;
        }


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your statement ````KMH_catone = 119 >= 153;```` will not work. With that you do a comparison ````119 >= 153```` that is always false. False will be converted to 0 and then assigned to KMH_catone. So, this will not work. You need to enter each windspeed in a variable by istelf, or, use the far better approach, where you put all windspeeds in a container.

Comment: You start off correctly with `if (kmh_windspeed < 119 )`, but then start to guess syntax, why? Go on like that: `if(wind is slower than threshold for cat 1) { ... } else if( wind is slower than threshold for cat 2) { ... } else if  ...`